# How can I resize this carousel I took from a demo site?

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I used this demo carousel for a site I'm working on and some images are appearing as stretched.  But the carousel area with the main image is actually quite wide and I'd like to increase the height.  I've tried amending the height but I'm not quite sure I'm targeting the right div.  Some simply increase the margins / space between the enlarged image and the thumbnails when I increase the height.  I inspected the element and found that they've in a way created margins and the centre is the main carousel / slider.  But I'm not sure where exactly I need to amend the code, specifically the height.

I've tried a few of the divs, particularly where it mentions height at 320px but this simply affects the image, not the container where the enlarged image is shown.

The carousel I'm using is here:
https://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.slider

Code is :

```js
jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

  var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [{
      $Duration: 800,
      x: 0.3,
      $During: {
        $Left: [0.3, 0.7]
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      x: -0.3,
      $SlideOut: true,
      $Easing: {
        $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      x: -0.3,
      $During: {
        $Left: [0.3, 0.7]
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      x: 0.3,
      $SlideOut: true,
      $Easing: {
        $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      y: 0.3,
      $During: {
        $Top: [0.3, 0.7]
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      y: -0.3,
      $SlideOut: true,
      $Easing: {
        $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      y: -0.3,
      $During: {
        $Top: [0.3, 0.7]
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      y: 0.3,
      $SlideOut: true,
      $Easing: {
        $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      x: 0.3,
      $Cols: 2,
      $During: {
        $Left: [0.3, 0.7]
      },
      $ChessMode: {
        $Column: 3
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      x: 0.3,
      $Cols: 2,
      $SlideOut: true,
      $ChessMode: {
        $Column: 3
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      y: 0.3,
      $Rows: 2,
      $During: {
        $Top: [0.3, 0.7]
      },
      $ChessMode: {
        $Row: 12
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      y: 0.3,
      $Rows: 2,
      $SlideOut: true,
      $ChessMode: {
        $Row: 12
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      y: 0.3,
      $Cols: 2,
      $During: {
        $Top: [0.3, 0.7]
      },
      $ChessMode: {
        $Column: 12
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      y: -0.3,
      $Cols: 2,
      $SlideOut: true,
      $ChessMode: {
        $Column: 12
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      x: 0.3,
      $Rows: 2,
      $During: {
        $Left: [0.3, 0.7]
      },
      $ChessMode: {
        $Row: 3
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      x: -0.3,
      $Rows: 2,
      $SlideOut: true,
      $ChessMode: {
        $Row: 3
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      x: 0.3,
      y: 0.3,
      $Cols: 2,
      $Rows: 2,
      $During: {
        $Left: [0.3, 0.7],
        $Top: [0.3, 0.7]
      },
      $ChessMode: {
        $Column: 3,
        $Row: 12
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      x: 0.3,
      y: 0.3,
      $Cols: 2,
      $Rows: 2,
      $During: {
        $Left: [0.3, 0.7],
        $Top: [0.3, 0.7]
      },
      $SlideOut: true,
      $ChessMode: {
        $Column: 3,
        $Row: 12
      },
      $Easing: {
        $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      $Delay: 20,
      $Clip: 3,
      $Assembly: 260,
      $Easing: {
        $Clip: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      $Delay: 20,
      $Clip: 3,
      $SlideOut: true,
      $Assembly: 260,
      $Easing: {
        $Clip: $Jease$.$OutCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      $Delay: 20,
      $Clip: 12,
      $Assembly: 260,
      $Easing: {
        $Clip: $Jease$.$InCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    },
    {
      $Duration: 800,
      $Delay: 20,
      $Clip: 12,
      $SlideOut: true,
      $Assembly: 260,
      $Easing: {
        $Clip: $Jease$.$OutCubic,
        $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
      },
      $Opacity: 2
    }
  ];

  var jssor_1_options = {
    $AutoPlay: 1,
    $SlideshowOptions: {
      $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
      $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
      $TransitionsOrder: 1
    },
    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
      $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
    },
    $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
      $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
      $SpacingX: 5,
      $SpacingY: 5
    }
  };

  var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

  /*#region responsive code begin*/

  var MAX_WIDTH = 980;

  function ScaleSlider() {
    var containerElement = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode;
    var containerWidth = containerElement.clientWidth;

    if (containerWidth) {

      var expectedWidth = Math.min(MAX_WIDTH || containerWidth, containerWidth);

      jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(expectedWidth);
    } else {
      window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }
  }

  ScaleSlider();

  $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
  $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
  $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
  /*#endregion responsive code end*/
};
```

```css
/*jssor slider loading skin spin css*/

.jssorl-009-spin img {
  animation-name: jssorl-009-spin;
  animation-duration: 1.6s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes jssorl-009-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


/*jssor slider arrow skin 106 css*/

.jssora106 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jssora106 .c {
  fill: #fff;
  opacity: .3;
}

.jssora106 .a {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 350;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jssora106:hover .c {
  opacity: .5;
}

.jssora106:hover .a {
  opacity: .8;
}

.jssora106.jssora106dn .c {
  opacity: .2;
}

.jssora106.jssora106dn .a {
  opacity: 1;
}

.jssora106.jssora106ds {
  opacity: .3;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/*jssor slider thumbnail skin 101 css*/

.jssort101 .p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #000;
}

.jssort101 .p .cv {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
}

.jssort101 .a {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 400;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.jssort101 .p:hover .cv,
.jssort101 .p.pdn .cv {
  border: none;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.jssort101 .p:hover {
  padding: 2px;
}

.jssort101 .p:hover .cv {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 6);
  opacity: .35;
}

.jssort101 .p:hover.pdn {
  padding: 0;
}

.jssort101 .p:hover.pdn .cv {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: none;
  opacity: .35;
}

.jssort101 .pav .cv {
  border-color: #fff;
  opacity: .35;
}

.jssort101 .pav .a,
.jssort101 .p:hover .a {
  visibility: visible;
}

.jssort101 .t {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  opacity: .6;
}

.jssort101 .pav .t,
.jssort101 .p:hover .t {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://jssors8.azureedge.net/script/jssor.slider-27.5.0.min.js"></script>


<div id="jssor_1" style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;top:0px;left:0px;width:980px;height:480px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
  <!-- Loading Screen -->
  <div data-u="loading" class="jssorl-009-spin" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
    <img style="margin-top:-19px;position:relative;top:50%;width:38px;height:38px;" src="img/spin.svg" />
  </div>
  <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:980px;height:320px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div>
      <img data-u="image" src="Carousel/WeddingCakes/3tierseminakedwedcake.jpg" />
      <img data-u="thumb" src="Carousel/WeddingCakes/3tierseminakedwedcake99x99.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img data-u="image" src="img/032.jpg" />
      <img data-u="thumb" src="img/032-s190x90.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img data-u="image" src="img/033.jpg" />
      <img data-u="thumb" src="img/033-s190x90.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img data-u="image" src="img/034.jpg" />
      <img data-u="thumb" src="img/034-s190x90.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img data-u="image" src="img/035.jpg" />
      <img data-u="thumb" src="img/035-s190x90.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img data-u="image" src="img/036.jpg" />
      <img data-u="thumb" src="img/036-s190x90.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img data-u="image" src="img/037.jpg" />
      <img data-u="thumb" src="img/037-s190x90.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img data-u="image" src="img/038.jpg" />
      <img data-u="thumb" src="img/038-s190x90.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img data-u="image" src="img/039.jpg" />
      <img data-u="thumb" src="img/039-s190x90.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img data-u="image" src="img/040.jpg" />
      <img data-u="thumb" src="img/040-s190x90.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Thumbnail Navigator -->
  <div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort101" style="position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;width:980px;height:100px;background-color:#000;" data-autocenter="1" data-scale-bottom="0.75">
    <div data-u="slides">
      <div data-u="prototype" class="p" style="width:190px;height:90px;">
        <div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
        <svg viewbox="0 0 16000 16000" class="cv">
                        <circle class="a" cx="8000" cy="8000" r="3238.1"></circle>
                        <line class="a" x1="6190.5" y1="8000" x2="9809.5" y2="8000"></line>
                        <line class="a" x1="8000" y1="9809.5" x2="8000" y2="6190.5"></line>
                    </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
  <div data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora106" style="width:55px;height:55px;top:162px;left:30px;" data-scale="0.75">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 16000 16000" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;">
                <circle class="c" cx="8000" cy="8000" r="6260.9"></circle>
                <polyline class="a" points="7930.4,5495.7 5426.1,8000 7930.4,10504.3 "></polyline>
                <line class="a" x1="10573.9" y1="8000" x2="5426.1" y2="8000"></line>
            </svg>
  </div>
  <div data-u="arrowright" class="jssora106" style="width:55px;height:55px;top:162px;right:30px;" data-scale="0.75">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 16000 16000" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;">
                <circle class="c" cx="8000" cy="8000" r="6260.9"></circle>
                <polyline class="a" points="8069.6,5495.7 10573.9,8000 8069.6,10504.3 "></polyline>
                <line class="a" x1="5426.1" y1="8000" x2="10573.9" y2="8000"></line>
            </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post what you've coded so far, and also -- in your post, please use the single apostrophe key instead of the backtick key.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I`ve updated with the code from where I assume the main carousel code begins.  The code prior to this is mainly jquery code so I have left out.

Comment: to just resize the component, change the value of the inline style, in the very first line of your code: `width:980px; height:480px;`.

Comment: Thanks - I`ve tried this, however this simply increases the space between the enlarged image and the thumbnails below it

Comment: also on the 6th line `width:980px;height:320px`. Do you have any prior knowledge of HTML?

Comment: @Mav455 please post the jquery code and your css

Comment: I have a basic knowledge of HTML- This is my first time working on a carousel and so I've used an example from online.  This is about the 3rd one I've tried as I encountered problems with the prior ones but this seems to work apart from this height issue I'm trying to resolve. I edited the 6th line and this enlarges the image but its still inside the same container/box so the image just appears zoomed in.  The container/box is what I want to increase the height on.

Comment: I`ve added the jquery code however I think the css is linked online.  I've taken the element from here, hence links to jssor where the code can be downloaded from: https://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.slider

Comment: @Mav455 please add some images. Without images (with full urls), it's difficult to solve your issue. I added the script for jssor js